# Where does the string "Segmentation Fault" come from?

Tags: unix, segmentation-fault

I have a program that generates a segmentation fault. Deliberately. I'm writing a programming book and I want to show what happens when you index out of bounds.

But now I want to catch the output of that program to include in the book, and I can't catch the actual string "Segmentation Fault". Where does it come from and where does it go to?

```
./segmentation 2>/dev/null 1>&2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Not standard out or error but what?

Answer (score -1):

> Where does it come from

From your `$SHELL`.

> and where does it go to?

To your terminal (duh!).

If you want to capture that string into a file, you could do something like this:

```
$SHELL -c './segmentation' > foo.txt 2>&1
```

P.S.

> I'm writing a programming book and I want to show what happens when you index out of bounds.

It doesn't sound to me like you know what actually happens, so perhaps writing a book on that is a bit premature.

Comment: Oh, catch the whole shell, rather than the code. Good one.

But no need for insults.